# Efficient manual cleanup of foreign keys in MySQL

Tags: mysql, foreign-key, null

I have an all-InnoDB database in MySQL (Percona) 5.6 that was previously using FK constraints. I had to give up on them as I kept running into locking issues, so I removed the constraints and added some manual cleanup maintenance scripts instead. These queries are causing problems as they appear to be very inefficient, so I'm wondering how they can be made to work more efficiently.

A typical arrangement is this:

## t1

`id, field1`

## t2

`id, t1_id, field1`

`t1_id` in `t2` is a foreign key pointing at the `id` field of `t1`. Each table has `id` set as its primary key, and `t2` has a regular index on `t1_id`.

So, instead of a foreign key constraint dealing with cascade deleting records in `t2` when a parent record in `t1` is deleted, I have a cleanup query like this:

```
DELETE t2.* FROM t2 LEFT JOIN t1 ON t1.id = t2.t1_id WHERE t2.t1_id IS NOT NULL AND t1.id IS NULL;
```

in other words, delete any record in `t2` that points at a non-existent record in `t1`.

That works, but it's *really* slow. Here's the explain for it:

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+---------------+---------+----------+--------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref           | rows    | filtered | Extra                                |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+---------------+---------+----------+--------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t2    | range  | t1_id         | t1_id   | 5       | NULL          | 2392097 |   100.00 | Using where                          |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t1    | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | mydb.t2.t1_id |       1 |   100.00 | Using where; Not exists; Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+---------------+---------+----------+--------------------------------------+
```

The obvious problem here is that the row count is very high, and other questions I've seen on this subject suggest the `range` match type is at the root of the problem. If I omit the check for `NOT NULL` on `t1_id`, it matches the whole of the `t2` table, making the row count even higher.

Because this is a single query, it tends to lock everything in t2 until it's complete, holding up other queries. I tried replacing it with separate select and delete, but it doesn't help much.

How can this be done better?

Comment: Find out how many what the min/ max values for table column t2.id is and loop through for a smaller set of records. For example if you have 100,000 records, then create a loop that looks at ranges of maybe 2000 at a time.

Comment: I would be careful blindly deleting foreign keys. You might be better off to index the foreign key columns in the referencing tables.

Comment: Did/Do you have indexes on the tables? I'd never consider dropping FK constraints and implementing the behaviour myself. I suggest you investigate better where and why the locking issues arise.

Comment: And why do you need an always running cleanup query anyway? Why not delete the related rows of `t2` whenever you delete a row in `t1` (and in the same transaction to ensure a consistent state of your database)?

Comment: @BateTech I'm not blindly deleting anything - I removed the FK specifically to avoid a very common locking situation, and removing them solved that problem, but made this one. I have appropriate indices on these tables, as stated in the Q. I can't really look for a smaller set since it's the looking for them that's the problem, not the finding of them (i.e. LIMIT would make no difference) - if there are any matches there are very probably only a few.

Comment: @ypercube Locks due to FKs are a very common issue (it's part of the tradeoff that FK's bring), and this approach to dealing with it is very common too, much like denormalising. It's done as a cleanup because that helps maintain code separation (avoids having one model deleting records from another's table), but it's not a bad idea to do as you suggest.

Comment: Using a transaction presents similar problems to the FKs - it will lock records in both tables simultaneously, instead of one at a time. I don't know about you, but I can't afford to have my app lock up for 10 minutes at a time...

Comment: Deleting a row (or a few rows) takes milliseconds. Why would your app need minutes for that?

Comment: I don't know why, but finding the rows to delete seems to take a long time (i.e. a select with the same criteria takes about the same amount of time as a delete), even though they are indexed. Some tables contain tens of millions of records.

Comment: How often is this query running?  Immediately after each parent is deleted, or as a scheduled job that is intended to delete batches of orphaned records at the same time?

Comment: Becasue it's slow and expensive, I only run it occasionally (hourly).

Comment: OK my point about breaking into smaller sets is that you can reduce the locking and time per `DELETE` statement (which seems to be the root of your issue) if you do so, by only processing small sets at a time from `t2`, and checking to see if they exist in `t1` in smaller batches.

Answer (score 1):

Try batching the deletes, so that you are only checking a small set of records at a time, and so are locking a smaller set of records.  You can play around with increase or decreasing the size of `@batchSize` until you find the "magic number" that performs best for you.  Note: I don't normally work in `MySQL` so my `while` loop syntax may not be 100% correct, but the general idea is there.

```
DECLARE @i int;
DECLARE @batchSize int;
DECLARE @maxKey int;

SET @i = 0;
SET @batchSize = 2000;
SET @maxKey = (select max(id) from t2 where t2.tl_id IS NOT NULL);


WHILE (@i < @maxKey) DO
BEGIN
    DELETE t2
    FROM t2
    LEFT JOIN t1 ON t2.t1_id = t1.id
    WHERE t2.id >= @i and t2.id <= @i + @batchSize
        AND t2.t1_id is not null
        AND t1.ID is null
    ;

    SET @i = @i + @batchSize;
END WHILE
```